# Deletion of Cassandra table entries with timestamp older than given timestamp

Tags: cassandra, cql, ttl

I want to delete all entries from a table requests that are older than a given timestamp.

the structure of the table requests:

```
CREATE TABLE requests (
    request_id uuid,
    request_timestamp timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (request_id, request_timestamp)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (request_timestamp ASC)
```

Obviously following query does not work, since the primary key request_id has to be specified:

```
Delete from Requests where request_timestamp < givenTimestamp;
```

But when i have a huge table with millions of entries, it would be less than optimal to use a query with IN clause:

```
Delete from Requests where request_id in (id1, id2.....) and request_timestamp < givenTimestamp;
```

An option would be to use TTL ( Time to Live) but we want to keep the TTL for entries configurable and with TTL this would not be possible.

What other ways are there to delete old entries from a table?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing is that, as you already wrote, you need to supply a partition key to perform such deletes.

Supposing you want to delete all requests with timestamp less than a specific day every day, in order to efficient you could change your model and partition by "day" instead of `request_id`. Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE requests (
    day timestamp,
    request_id uuid,
    request_timestamp timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (day, request_timestamp, request_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (request_timestamp ASC, request_id ASC)
```

The field `day` is populated with a *truncation* of the `request_timestamp` to the *day* component only (eg `yyyy-mm-dd`). If you need to delete from multiple periods you'll need to run a bunch of parallel DELETE queries, one per day, and don't use `IN`. You'd also delete at partition level and not at cell level, and that's a big plus for reads.